# Structure of "Er bekommt die Frage gestellt"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

From [Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/schottland-referendum-a-992381.html):

> US-Präsident Barack Obama befürwortet dagegen ein vereinigtes Königreich - und bekommt dafür die Frage gestellt, wann denn die USA wieder ins UK eintreten würden.

What is the structure behind

> Obama bekommt die Frage gestellt, wann ...

?

In particular, it seems weird that "gestellt" appears at the end of the main clause.

What are some other examples of this sentence structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a passive voice construction.

> Er bekommt die Frage gestellt
> Er bekommt ein Buch geschenkt

The specific type of question (or the description of the book) can be inserted in different places.

> Er bekommt die Frage gestellt, wann ...
> Er bekommt die Frage, wann ..., gestellt.
>
> Er bekommt ein Buch geschenkt, in dem ...
> Er bekommt ein Buch, in dem ..., geschenkt.

Answer (score 2):

It's just regular passive voice: He gets asked a question.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a regular passive voice, but it can be regarded as a passive voice construction: http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktiv_und_Passiv_im_Deutschen#Passiv_mit_.E2.80.9Ebekommen.E2.80.9C

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Thanks! That's exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Other examples of this sentence structure can be found in other analytical verb forms:

> 1. Obama *stellt* die Frage. (Präsens)
> 2. Obama *hat* die Frage *gestellt*. (Präsensperfekt)
> 3. Obama *wird* die Frage *stellen*. (Futur)
> 4. Obama *wird* die Frage *gestellt*. (Passiv)
> 5. Obama *will* die Frage *stellen*. (Modal verb)

The finite auxiliar takes the place of the finite verb (as seen in the first sentence), the infinite Verb or Participle moves to the end of the sentence.

The construction seen in 3. and mentioned by you is called "Rezipientenpassiv". It can also used with "kriegen" as auxiliary:

> Obama kriegt die Frage gestellt.

However, "kriegen" is regarded as bad style. AFAIK it is still subject to debate whether the Rezipientenpassiv is grammaticalized.

Comment: Und was hat der Hauptteil der Antwort mit "bekommt die Frage gestellt" zu tun?

Comment: Die Frage war: "In particular, it seems weird that "gestellt" appears at the end of the main clause. What are some other examples of this sentence structure?". Ich wollte darauf hinaus, dass das die übliche Struktur analytischer Konjugationsformen des Deutschen ist.