# How to express that something was done not by me, but for/to me?

Tags: passive

> a. I have Windows installed
>
> b. I have my hair cut

The only solution I found was the verb *lassen*. Still remains unclear how to use it, how to translate in an appropriate way.

And also very important: Are there any other solutions besides that with the word *lassen*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is also possible to use "Rezipientenpassiv" (bekommen + Partizip Perfekt):

> Ich *bekomme* Windows *installiert*
>   Ich *bekomme* die Haare *geschnitten*

Comment: Would you really ever say it that way?

Comment: Absolutely. _Morgen bekomme ich die neuen Möbel geliefert_ is a perfect example.

Comment: Well, the first sentence does sound a bit odd, but it's not wrong per se.

Comment: We had it here a few days back in another example: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15754/structure-of-er-bekommt-die-frage-gestellt

Answer (score 8):

> "Ich lasse mir Windows installieren"
>
> "Ich lasse mir die Haare schneiden"

This is what I would normally say.

Somewhat more formal, and probably rarely used in spoken German :

> "Mir wird Windows installiert"
>
> "Mir werden die Haare geschnitten ".

The latter option (i.e. the passive construction) has a slightly different connotation - while the first option implies that you actually wanted someone to cut your hair/ install Windows, the latter is neutral in this respect.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Gerhard! Perfect and comprehensive answer! Helped a lot!

Comment: @gerhard Shouldn't it be "ich habe ... installieren gelassen"/"ich habe ... schneiden gelassen"?

Comment: @karoshi: the only thing I can say: sounds wrong to me - but I cannot give you a grammatical explanation, unfortunately. I probably wouldn't even notice if someone else said this, but I would never say so myself...

Comment: @karoshi: No, I'm afraid it's _ich habe + inf. + lassen_.

Comment: @Ingmar Interesting. Then if one wanted to use the present perfect would it be "Ich habe ... lassen gehabt"?

Comment: @karoshi No, it would be "Ich hatte ... lassen"

Comment: @karoshi: Gerhard's solution is in the "perfect" form. A "present perfect" does not exist in the German language.

Comment: @arne: That would be "past perfect" / Plusquamperfekt, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarcMosby Yeah, sorry, my bad. Didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @karoshi yes, i think "gelassen" is gramatically correct, as long as we're dealing with "Perfect".

Comment: @a-herrmann I found a thread that explains why "gelassen" is plain wrong: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=106191&langid=3

Comment: @MarcMosby Of course, the double infinitive! I should have known it. Thanks.

Comment: Why present perfect? The English sentences in the question use present tense.

Comment: @Carsten: you are correct, of course. I edited mt answer to match the original English sentence.